# If sentence with a text condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I need to write an if loop in pyhon. My condition is related to a text (dict_keys). in particular, i have:

```
condition = f.get_best().keys()
```

When i read the condition element, it returns:

```
dict_keys(['laplace'])
```

Where i can have 'laplace' or 'gumbel'.
My goal is to perform different calculation if laplace or gumbel is returned.
My attempt so far:

```
condition = f.get_best().keys()
if condition == dict_keys(['laplace']):
 print('Laplace case')
elif condition == dict_keys(['gumbel']):
 print('gumbel case')
```

But it doesn't work. i also tried with:

```
if condition == laplace:
if condition == 'laplace':
```

But none of these seem  to work. How can i do it?

Comment: What is `condition` and what is `dict_keys()`? What do you expect them to be?

Comment: can you do a `print(condition)` and `print(type(condition))` and post the results, so we can see what datatypes are you working with?

Comment: When i read the content of 'condition', i read 'dict_keys(['laplace'])'. My goal is to read be able to detect that in 'condition' it is written 'laplace' or whatever, and set this as a condition.

Comment: print(distribution): dict_keys(['laplace'])
print(type(distribution)): <class 'dict_keys'>

Comment: you are not using `distribution` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`dict_keys` can't be used explicitly, it's internal of a dictionary.
 Use the following instead:

```
best_keys = f.get_best().keys()
if 'laplace' in best_keys:
    print('Laplace case')
elif 'gumbel' in best_keys:
    print('gumbel case')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change condition to a list and then compare the list with what you want it to be.
Would be done like this.
`if list(condition) == ['laplace']:`

(if the dictionary has multiple keys you should use `in`).

Answer (score 0):

One could use `match`. This makes addition of new cases fairly easy.

```py
>>> def lagumbl(cnd):
...     match cnd:
...             case "laplace":
...                     print(f["laplace"])
...             case "gumbel":
...                     print(f["gumbel"])
... 
>>> for cond in f.get_best().keys():
...     lagumbl(cnd=cond)
... 
laplace here
gumbel here
```